"Add new record" to Sharepoint form
I have a Sharepoint form which has been designed to record changes to product forecasts. I would like to know if there is a way to include an "Add New Record" button within the form itself. Once that button is clicked, a field/s appears which the user can then populate with product code, and quantity. All I have now are preconfigured entries for Product 1, Product 2, Product 3 etc, but the number of products may change each time the form is used. And it looks messy with wasted space as well. Sharepoint form
I have searched multiple sites and tried JSON code which i have found on other sites, but all I can find is Add second button, concatenation. No solution can be found. My JSON skills are rudimentary at best.
